# Why is Vim stopping me from changing tabs?

Tags: macos, terminal, vim, tabs

I'm using MacVim with a few tabs open.  To keep everything from one project in one window I'd like to make one of those tabs into a terminal.

So I switch to a tab and type

```
:!bash
```

I get a lovely terminal within the tab.  The problem is that MacVim WON'T permit me to leave that tab without exiting the shell. What's going on here?

[image]

Comment: I already [answered](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/4xuwb4/why_is_macvim_stopping_me_from_changing_tabs/d6iq3na) your question on reddit.

Comment: This isn't meant to answer your question directly, but if you do a lot of terminal work within vim, have you considered using neovim instead? It has a built-in terminal that works quite well.